# How to change the color of a JButton when the name of the JButton I want to color is in a string?

Tags: java, string, user-interface, methods, jbutton

I have a random number method and random color method set up. I have 28 buttons and they all are named button_number. The random number picks the button. I have some basic code that obviously doesn't work because I can't change the background of the string but I don't know where to go from here.

```
static Random random = new Random();
static int rand1 = RandomRange.showRandomInteger(1, 28, random);
static String num = Integer.toString(rand1);
static String button = ("button_" + num);

button.setBackground(randomColor());
```

other class

```
public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                TestFrame frame = new TestFrame();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public TestFrame() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
    contentPane.add(layeredPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JButton btnTick = new JButton("Tick");
    btnTick.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        }
    });
    btnTick.setBounds(281, 217, 133, 23);
    layeredPane.add(btnTick);

    JButton btnStart = new JButton("Start");
    btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        }
    });
    btnStart.setBounds(10, 217, 133, 23);
    layeredPane.add(btnStart);


    JButton button_27 = new JButton("");
    button_27.setBounds(0, 0, 45, 45);
    layeredPane.add(button_27);

    JButton button_28 = new JButton("");
    button_28.setBackground(Color.RED);
    button_28.setBounds(45, 0, 45, 45);
    layeredPane.add(button_28);

    JButton button_1 = new JButton("");
    button_1.setBounds(90, 0, 45, 45);
    layeredPane.add(button_1);

    JButton button_2 = new JButton("");
    button_2.setBounds(135, 0, 45, 45);
    layeredPane.add(button_2);

    JButton button_3 = new JButton("");
    button_3.setBounds(180, 0, 45, 45);
    layeredPane.add(button_3);

    JButton button_4 = new JButton("");
    button_4.setBounds(225, 0, 45, 45);
    layeredPane.add(button_4);

    JButton button_5 = new JButton("");
    button_5.setBounds(270, 0, 45, 45);
    layeredPane.add(button_5);

    JButton button_6 = new JButton("");
    button_6.setBounds(270, 45, 45, 45);
    layeredPane.add(button_6);

    JButton button_7 = new JButton("");
    button_7.setBounds(0, 45, 45, 45);
    layeredPane.add(button_7);

    JButton button_8 = new JButton("");
    button_8.setBounds(225, 45, 45, 45);
    layeredPane.add(button_8);

    JButton button_9 = new JButton("");
    button_9.setBounds(45, 45, 45, 45);
    layeredPane.add(button_9);

    JButton button_10 = new JButton("");
    button_10.setBounds(90, 45, 45, 45);
    layeredPane.add(button_10);

    JButton button_11 = new JButton("");
    button_11.setBounds(135, 45, 45, 45);
    layeredPane.add(button_11);

    JButton button_12 = new JButton("");
    button_12.setBounds(180, 45, 45, 45);
    layeredPane.add(button_12);

    JButton button_13 = new JButton("");
    button_13.setBounds(0, 135, 45, 45);
    layeredPane.add(button_13);

    JButton button_14 = new JButton("");
    button_14.setBounds(0, 90, 45, 45);
    layeredPane.add(button_14);

    JButton button_15 = new JButton("");
    button_15.setBounds(45, 90, 45, 45);
    layeredPane.add(button_15);

    JButton button_16 = new JButton("");
    button_16.setBounds(45, 135, 45, 45);
    layeredPane.add(button_16);

    JButton button_17 = new JButton("");
    button_17.setBounds(90, 135, 45, 45);
    layeredPane.add(button_17);

    JButton button_18 = new JButton("");
    button_18.setBounds(90, 90, 45, 45);
    layeredPane.add(button_18);

    JButton button_19 = new JButton("");
    button_19.setBounds(135, 90, 45, 45);
    layeredPane.add(button_19);

    JButton button_20 = new JButton("");
    button_20.setBounds(135, 135, 45, 45);
    layeredPane.add(button_20);

    JButton button_21 = new JButton("");
    button_21.setBounds(180, 135, 45, 45);
    layeredPane.add(button_21);

    JButton button_22 = new JButton("");
    button_22.setBounds(180, 90, 45, 45);
    layeredPane.add(button_22);

    JButton button_23 = new JButton("");
    button_23.setBounds(225, 90, 45, 45);
    layeredPane.add(button_23);

    JButton button_24 = new JButton("");
    button_24.setBounds(225, 135, 45, 45);
    layeredPane.add(button_24);

    JButton button_25 = new JButton("");
    button_25.setBounds(270, 135, 45, 45);
    layeredPane.add(button_25);

    JButton button_26 = new JButton("");
    button_26.setBounds(270, 90, 45, 45);
    layeredPane.add(button_26);

    final JButton[] BUTTONS = {button_1,button_2,button_3,button_4,button_5,button_6,button_7,
            button_8,button_9,button_10,button_11,button_12,button_13,button_14,button_15,
            button_16,button_17,button_18,button_19,button_20,button_21,button_22,button_23,
            button_24,button_25,button_26,button_27,button_28};



    JLabel label = new JLabel("Blue:");
    label.setBounds(325, 11, 89, 14);
    layeredPane.add(label);

    JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("Yellow:");
    label_1.setBounds(325, 36, 89, 14);
    layeredPane.add(label_1);

    JLabel label_2 = new JLabel("Red:");
    label_2.setBounds(325, 61, 89, 14);
    layeredPane.add(label_2);
}
```

}

Comment: Is this a Java question?  You are going to need to supply more detail and code before you will get an answer, I imagine.

Comment: Don't use null layouts, you don't control the aspects which will change the size of the components when rendered on different systems

Answer (score 1):

The name of the button is the label of the button.  Keep your buttons in a collection.  Iterate through the collection to match the button's .getName () with your string.  Then call the button's setBackgroundColor to change the button color.

Comment: How would I get a JButton[] from the GUI class(added to question) into my tick class?(already shown)

Comment: @toxicswagger1 I would programmatically calculate the bounds of the buttons.  I would make a special button class.  Since you are creating (instancing) the buttons directly in the code one by one, you can give them labels (and hence names) that correspond to the numbers.  You can also add them one by one to an array or collection of your own making without trying to pull such an array out of the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Pass color code as a String like for red color use this: button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
or
button.setBackground(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));

Answer (score 0):

Put all the buttons in an array or `List`.  When you calculate the random number, look up the button in the list/array and change its Color property

Comment: Yes I just did that(question updated) but I don't know how to bring the array over to the other class.

Comment: You will either need to pass the reference of the array to the other class, probably not a good idea, or pass back the random value/color to the class containing the array...